# Convert Guava's ArrayListMultimap to Serializable Map

Tags: java, serialization, guava

Is it posible to convert an `ArrayListMultimap` in a `Serializable` `Map`? Of course keys and values are Serializable.

I know `ArrayListMultimap` is serializable but I want to serialize it as a plain `Map` because I don't want the deserializer have to know about guava Multimaps.

I've tried this:

```
    ArrayListMultimap<String, Integer> mmap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    mmap.put("key",1);
    mmap.put("key",222222222);

    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    //This works fine
    out.writeObject(mmap);
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = Multimaps.asMap(mmap);
    try {
        out.writeObject(map);
    } catch (NotSerializableException e){
        //Multimaps.asMap is not Serializable, seems reasonable to me
    }

    ImmutableMap<String, List<Integer>> imap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(map);
    //Will throw java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$RandomAccessWrappedList. Oh man!! why!??
    out.writeObject(imap);
```

Then, is there a way (an efficient way hopefully) to convert an `ArrayListMultimap` in a Serializable Map, this is: a Map with Serializable Lists in it?

I'm using guava-18.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the map values into `Serializable` lists using [`Maps.transformValues(Map, Function)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function)):

```
imap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(Maps.transformValues(map, ImmutableList::copyOf));
```